# Определение максимальной амплитуды уровня звука микрофона ОС Андроид

Tags: java, android

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

<TextView android:text="dB" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static TextView tv1;
    public int max = 0;
    public static Timer mTimer;
    public static MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask;
    public int minSize;
    public AudioRecord ar;
    public short[] buffer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        minSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minSize);

        tv1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 0, 400);

    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (ar.getState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED) {
                        buffer = new short[minSize];
                        ar.startRecording();
                        ar.read(buffer, 0, minSize);
                        max = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
                            short b = buffer[i];
                            if (b < 0) b = (short) -b;
                            if (b > max) max = b;
                        }
                        tv1.setText("" + max);
                        ar.stop();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer = null;
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

Это рабочий вариант для ОС Андроид 4.1.
Подскажите, плиз, почему не работает для 5-ой версии?
И есть ли альтернативное решение?
Благодарю заранее...

Comment: А что конкретного не работает в 5 версии? Возникает ошибка или что?

Comment: Всегда показывает ноль. Ошибок нет. Вы можете скопировать все 3 файла соответственно в свой новый проект и непосредственно увидите!

Comment: Дебажить не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал. Не нахожу! Вот и решил, может альтернативное, более простое решение есть?

Comment: Я веду к тому, что за вас никто не будет дебажить/искать ошибку. Если вы скажите, что "вот в этом месте такая ошибка, в чем может быть причина", тогда вам помогут

Comment: Все зависит от уровня помощника, опыта и его желания помочь. В данном случае у вас что-то из этого отсутствует или всё вместе. Другие помогали и в более сложном)) В любом случае, спасибо за интерес, проявленный к моему вопросу!

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, эту статью http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , а конкретнее главу "Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать"

Comment: Вопрос решен. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Приложите в ответе, как вы его решили. Возможно, кому то понадобится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

    private boolean stop;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        AudioRecord ar;
        short[] audioBuffer;
        int MHz = 16000;
        int ms  = 1;
        int minSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(MHz, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, MHz, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minSize);
        audioBuffer = new short[minSize];
        ar.startRecording();
        stop = false;
        int delay = 0;
        while (!stop) {
            final int readSize = ar.read(audioBuffer, 0, minSize);
            delay += readSize;
            double amplitude = 0;
            double sum=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
                sum += audioBuffer[i] * audioBuffer[i];
            }
            amplitude = sum / readSize / 10000.;

            if(delay > MHz*ms/10) { // ms*100 миллисекунд
                delay = 0;
                final int finalAmplitude = (int) amplitude;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv1.setText(""+finalAmplitude);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        ar.stop();
    }

    public void stopRecording() {stop = true;}
}

    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (thread != null) thread.stopRecording();
    finish();
}
```

}